# Как скачать zip с ftp сервера?

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно программно загрузить несколько zip файлов с определенным именами с удаленного сервера по ftp?

Comment: необходимо: написать класс и метод загрузки файла, класс и метод коннекта к ФТП, передать в метод параметры необходимых к скачиванию файлов и передать параметры для подключения к FTP

Comment: Нужно - качайте. В чем вопрос - не ясно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот скачиваете файл с FTP-сервера с помощью `WebClient`:

```
private void DownloadFileFTP()
{
    string inputfilepath = @"C:\Temp\FileName.exe";
    string ftphost = "xxx.xx.x.xxx";
    string ftpfilepath = "/Updater/Dir1/FileName.exe";

    string ftpfullpath = "ftp://" + ftphost + ftpfilepath;

    using (WebClient request = new WebClient())
    {
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "P@55w0rd");
        byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData(ftpfullpath);

        using (FileStream file = File.Create(inputfilepath))
        {
            file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            file.Close();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Download Complete");
    }
}
```

Дополнительные материалы по теме:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781654/ftpwebrequest-download-file (англ.)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519290/downloading-files-using-ftpwebrequest (англ.)