# Почему скачиваются пустые файлы с FTP сервера?

Tags: c#, ftp

Использую BytesRoad.Net.Ftp, но она почему то перестала скачивать файлы (выдает ошибку Operation failed) или скачивает их пустыми (при этом на FTP-сервере файл не пуст).

```
ftp.GetFile(TimeOUT, destFile, sourceFile); //Ошибка тут
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Или посоветуйте хорошую библиотеку для работы с FTP.

Comment: Можешь, пожалуйста, вставить часть кода, чтобы поточнее разобраться с проблемой? Так сразу и не сказать что не так

Answer (score 0):

С c# я сейчас пока на вы, но рассмотри вариант ответа другого участника сообщества:

ссылка:

[Как скачать zip с FTP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557057/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-zip-%D1%81-ftp-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: Благодарю! Уже нашел ошибку) Проблема была в некорректном пути до нужного файла. А так библиотека хорошая)

Comment: Рад помочь) Удачи в программировании

Comment: Здравствуйте, может вы сможете подсказать по моей похожей проблеме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795261/c-ftp-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8